# Getting a error when trying to train using model.fit.generator

Tags: image, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I've been trying to figure out what my error is in my data set when using a fit_generator(....)

The terminal returns this error:
ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None

It appears that I'm not meeting the fit_generator requirements for data input and output, leading to an array issue. I looked u what a tuple is and found it's just an array of n.size.

If someone would be so kind as to take a look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong that would be great. Thanks :). In the meantime I'll keep trying things to fix the problem.

```
import csv
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import os
import h5py
import sklearn
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
np.random.seed(0)


def generator(images, measurements, batch_size):
    #    Generator to process a certain portion of the model at a time
    #    :param data_dir: The data directory
    #    :param image_paths: The paths to the images
    #    :param steer_angles: The steering angles
    #    :param batch_size: The batch size
    #    :param is_training: Whether this is training data (True) or validation data (False)
    num_samples = len(samples)
    while 1: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
        shuffle(samples)
        for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]

            images = []
            measurements = []
            for batch_sample in batch_samples:
                for i in range(3):
                    source_path = sample[i]
                    name = source_path.split('/')[-1]
                    current_path = '../data7/IMG/' + name
                    image = cv2.imread(current_path)
                    images.append(image)
                correction = 0.05 
                # Number was chosen with trail and error, I tried 1 and found the car was jerky.
                # I saw David use 0.02 and felt it was too week at times, so I selected 0.05. 
                measurement = float(sample[3])
                measurements.append(measurement)
                measurements.append(measurement+correction)
                measurements.append(measurement-correction)

            # import Images 
            augmented_images = []
            augmented_measurements = []
            for image, measurement in zip(images, measurements):
                augmented_images.append(image)
                augmented_measurements.append(measurement)
                flipped_image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
                flipped_measurement = float(measurement) * -1.0
                augmented_images.append(flipped_image)
                augmented_measurements.append(flipped_measurement)
                augmented_measurements.append(flipped_measurement+correction)
                augmented_measurements.append(flipped_measurement-correction)

        # trim image to only see section with road 
        X_data = np.array(augmented_images)
        y_data = np.array(augmented_measurements)
        print("X_train ", X_data.shape)
        print("y_train ", y_data.shape)
        yield sklearn.utils.shuffle(X_data, y_data)

# plot function to be called after running the model
def plot_results(history, num = 0):
    #Plot the results 
    #:param history: The fit model
    #:param num: The number for the output file to save to
    # Plot training and validation loss
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model mean squared error loss')
    plt.ylabel('mean squared error loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['training set', 'validation set'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('training_validation_loss_plot_' + str(num) + '.jpg')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

# import data 
samples = []
with open('../data7/driving_log.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for sample in reader:
                samples.append(sample)

# split Data into Traning and Validation 
test_size = 0.2
random_state = 0
# compile and train the model using the generator function
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_samples, validation_samples = train_test_split(samples,  test_size=test_size, random_state=random_state)
train_generator = generator(train_samples, batch_size=32)
validation_generator = generator(validation_samples, batch_size=32)

# print('train_generator:', train_generator.shape)
# print('validation_generator:', validation_generator.shape)
# Make lines a numpy array

# # from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(samples, test_size=test_size, random_state=random_state)
# X_train_generator = generator(X_train, batch_size=32)
# X_validation_generator = generator(X_valid, batch_size=32)
# y_train_generator = generator(y_train, batch_size=32)
# y_validation_generator = generator(y_valid, batch_size=32)


# print('X_train shape', X_train.shape)
# print('Y_train shape', y_train.shape)
# print('X_valid shape', X_valid.shape)
# print('y_valid shape', y_valid.shape)

# import infomation from keras for creating the learning model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Lambda, Dropout, Cropping2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# model peramiters 
keep_prob = 0.5
video_H = 160
viedo_L = 320
layers = 3
crop_H = 25
crop_W = 70


model = Sequential()
# model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=(video_H, viedo_L, layers)))
# Preprocess incoming data, centered around zero with small standard deviation 
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0 - 1., input_shape=(video_H, viedo_L, layers), output_shape=(video_H, viedo_L, layers)))
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((crop_W, crop_H), (0,0))))
model.add(Convolution2D(24,5,5, subsample=(2,2), activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(36,5,5, subsample=(2,2), activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(48,5,5, subsample=(2,2), activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(keep_prob))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()


#Create a checkpoint of the model 
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}.h0',
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=0,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='auto')

# set constant numbers for model generation
batch_size = 40
num_epochs = 10
samples_per_epoch = 20000
learn_rate = 0.0001

# create a model and save it
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam(lr=learn_rate))
#model.fit(images, steering, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, nb_epoch=epoch) - Used for Orginal training 

history_object = model.fit_generator(train_generator, samples_per_epoch=len(train_samples), validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=len(validation_samples), callbacks=[checkpoint], nb_epoch=5, verbose=1)

history = model.fit_generator(generator(X_train, y_train, batch_size,),
                    samples_per_epoch,
                    num_epochs,
                    max_q_size=1,
                    validation_data=generator(X_valid, y_valid, batch_size),
                    nb_val_samples=len(X_valid),
                    callbacks=[checkpoint],
                    verbose=1)

model.save('nvidia05.h5')
plot_results(history_object, 0)
exit()
```

Comment: Its very unclear. You should add complete stack trace along with some data if possible

Comment: If I see it correctly, your generator does not return anything. The first argument of `fit_generator`should be an `Iterator` with a `__next__` function returning two arrays `x_train, y_train`. which should contain a single batch